# android Vuforia multi target rotate object on touch

Tags: android, android-studio, vuforia

I created an android app using Vuforia 6. in this app i have 26 different target images and 26 different 3D object (1 Object on 1 target). that works perfectly, but i need to rotate 3d object on use touch.

here is my renderer code:

```
public class ImageTargetRendererAndroid implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer, SampleAppRendererControl
{
    private static final String LOGTAG = "ImageTargetRenderer";

    private SampleApplicationSession vuforiaAppSession;
    private ImageTargetsAndroid mActivity;
    private SampleAppRenderer mSampleAppRenderer;

    private Vector<Texture> mTextures;


    private int normalHandle;


    private int shaderProgramID;
    private int vertexHandle;
    private int textureCoordHandle;
    private int mvpMatrixHandle;
    private int texSampler2DHandle;
    private ArrayList<AndroidModel> mModel = new ArrayList<AndroidModel>();
    //private Teapot mTeapot;

    private float kBuildingScale = 12.0f;
    private SampleApplication3DModel mBuildingsModel;

    private Renderer mRenderer;

    boolean mIsActive = false;
    private boolean mModelIsLoaded = false;

    private static final float OBJECT_SCALE_FLOAT = 3.0f;

    ArrayList<String> modelNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    private Product mProduct;


    private String PackagePath = "";
    private String Package3DPath = "";

    AndroidModel curModel;

    public ImageTargetRendererAndroid(ImageTargetsAndroid activity, SampleApplicationSession session, Product product)
    {

        mProduct = product;
        PackagePath = Globals.getPackagePath(mProduct.getName());
        Package3DPath = PackagePath + Constants.SERVER_RESPONSE_TAGS_FOLDER_NAME_3D+ "/";



        if(modelNames.size() <= 0){
            ArrayList<String> names = Globals.getModelNames(Package3DPath);

            for(String name : names){
                modelNames.add(name);
            }
        }

//        modelNames.add("A");
//        modelNames.add("B");

        mActivity = activity;
        vuforiaAppSession = session;
        // SampleAppRenderer used to encapsulate the use of RenderingPrimitives setting
        // the device mode AR/VR and stereo mode
        mSampleAppRenderer = new SampleAppRenderer(this, mActivity, Device.MODE.MODE_AR, false, 10f , 5000f);
    }


    // Called to draw the current frame.
    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl)
    {
        if (!mIsActive)
            return;

        // Call our function to render content from SampleAppRenderer class
        mSampleAppRenderer.render();
    }


    public void setActive(boolean active)
    {
        mIsActive = active;

        if(mIsActive)
            mSampleAppRenderer.configureVideoBackground();
    }


    // Called when the surface is created or recreated.
    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config)
    {
        Log.d(LOGTAG, "GLRenderer.onSurfaceCreated");

        // Call Vuforia function to (re)initialize rendering after first use
        // or after OpenGL ES context was lost (e.g. after onPause/onResume):
        vuforiaAppSession.onSurfaceCreated();

        mSampleAppRenderer.onSurfaceCreated();
    }


    // Called when the surface changed size.
    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        Log.d(LOGTAG, "GLRenderer.onSurfaceChanged");

        // Call Vuforia function to handle render surface size changes:
        vuforiaAppSession.onSurfaceChanged(width, height);

        // RenderingPrimitives to be updated when some rendering change is done
        mSampleAppRenderer.onConfigurationChanged(mIsActive);

        initRendering();
    }


    // Function for initializing the renderer.
    private void initRendering()
    {

        String storage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/";

        ArrayList<String> objs = Globals.getModelObjects(Package3DPath);

//        for(String obj : objs){
//            //modelNames.add(Package3DPath + obj);
//            mModel.add(new AndroidModel(mActivity,Package3DPath + "/" + obj));
//        }

        if(modelNames.size() <= 0){
            ArrayList<String> names = Globals.getModelNames(Package3DPath);

            for(String name : names){
                modelNames.add(name);
            }
        }


        for(String modelName : modelNames){
            //modelNames.add(Package3DPath + obj);
            mModel.add(new AndroidModel(mActivity,Package3DPath + modelName + "." + Constants.FILE_TYPE_OBJ,modelName));
        }

//        mModel.add(new AndroidModel(mActivity,storage + "A.obj"));
//        mModel.add(new AndroidModel(mActivity,storage + "B.obj"));

        mRenderer = Renderer.getInstance();

        GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, Vuforia.requiresAlpha() ? 0.0f : 1.0f);

        for (Texture t : mTextures)
        {
            GLES20.glGenTextures(1, t.mTextureID, 0);
            GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, t.mTextureID[0]);
            GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
            GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
            GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, t.mWidth, t.mHeight, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, t.mData);
        }

        shaderProgramID = SampleUtils.createProgramFromShaderSrc( CubeShaders.CUBE_MESH_VERTEX_SHADER,  CubeShaders.CUBE_MESH_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

        vertexHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgramID, "vertexPosition");
        normalHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgramID, "vertexNormal");
        textureCoordHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgramID, "vertexTexCoord");
        mvpMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgramID, "modelViewProjectionMatrix");
        texSampler2DHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgramID, "texSampler2D");

        if(!mModelIsLoaded) {
            //mTeapot = new Teapot();

//            try {
//                mBuildingsModel = new SampleApplication3DModel();
//                mBuildingsModel.loadModel(mActivity.getResources().getAssets(), "ImageTargets/Buildings.txt");
//                mModelIsLoaded = true;
//            } catch (IOException e) {
//                Log.e(LOGTAG, "Unable to load buildings");
//            }

            // Hide the Loading Dialog
            mActivity.loadingDialogHandler.sendEmptyMessage(LoadingDialogHandler.HIDE_LOADING_DIALOG);
        }

    }

    public void updateConfiguration()
    {
        mSampleAppRenderer.onConfigurationChanged(mIsActive);
    }

    // The render function called from SampleAppRendering by using RenderingPrimitives views.
    // The state is owned by SampleAppRenderer which is controlling it's lifecycle.
    // State should not be cached outside this method.
    public void renderFrame(State state, float[] projectionMatrix)
    {
        // Renders video background replacing Renderer.DrawVideoBackground()
        mSampleAppRenderer.renderVideoBackground();

//        state = mRenderer.begin();
//        mRenderer.drawVideoBackground();

        GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);

        // handle face culling, we need to detect if we are using reflection
        // to determine the direction of the culling
        GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_CULL_FACE);
        GLES20.glCullFace(GLES20.GL_BACK);

        // Did we find any trackables this frame?
        int a = state.getNumTrackableResults();
        for (int tIdx = 0; tIdx < state.getNumTrackableResults(); tIdx++) {
            TrackableResult result = state.getTrackableResult(tIdx);
            Trackable trackable = result.getTrackable();

            Matrix44F modelViewMatrix_Vuforia = Tool.convertPose2GLMatrix(result.getPose());
            float[] modelViewMatrix = modelViewMatrix_Vuforia.getData();

//            int textureIndex = trackable.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("stones") ? 0 : 1;
//            textureIndex = trackable.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("tarmac") ? 2 : textureIndex;

            // deal with the modelview and projection matrices
            float[] modelViewProjection = new float[16];

            String targetdata = ((String) trackable.getUserData()).replace("Current Dataset : ","");

            int modelIndex = getTargetIndex(targetdata);

            int textureIndex = modelIndex;

            curModel = mModel.get(modelIndex);

            if (!mActivity.isExtendedTrackingActive()) {

                GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(vertexHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, curModel.getVertices());
                GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(normalHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, curModel.getNormals());
                GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(textureCoordHandle, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, curModel.getTexCoords());

                GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertexHandle);
                GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(normalHandle);
                GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(textureCoordHandle);

                // activate texture 0, bind it, and pass to shader
                GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
                GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextures.get(textureIndex).mTextureID[0]);
                GLES20.glUniform1i(texSampler2DHandle, 0);

                // pass the model view matrix to the shader
                GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mvpMatrixHandle, 1, false, modelViewProjection, 0);

                // finally draw the teapot
                GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, curModel.getNumObjectIndex(), GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, curModel.getIndices());

                // disable the enabled arrays
                GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(vertexHandle);
                GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(normalHandle);
                GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(textureCoordHandle);

            } else {

                GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_CULL_FACE);
                GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(vertexHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, mBuildingsModel.getVertices());
                GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(normalHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, mBuildingsModel.getNormals());
                GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(textureCoordHandle, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, mBuildingsModel.getTexCoords());

                GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertexHandle);
                GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(normalHandle);
                GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(textureCoordHandle);

                GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
                GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextures.get(3).mTextureID[0]);
                GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mvpMatrixHandle, 1, false, modelViewProjection, 0);
                GLES20.glUniform1i(texSampler2DHandle, 0);
                GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, mBuildingsModel.getNumObjectVertex());

                SampleUtils.checkGLError("Renderer DrawBuildings");

                Matrix.rotateM(modelViewMatrix, 0, 90.0f, 1.0f, 0, 0);
                Matrix.scaleM(modelViewMatrix, 0, kBuildingScale, kBuildingScale, kBuildingScale);
            }
            Matrix.multiplyMM(modelViewProjection, 0, projectionMatrix, 0, modelViewMatrix, 0);

            // activate the shader program and bind the vertex/normal/tex coords
            GLES20.glUseProgram(shaderProgramID);

            if (!mActivity.isExtendedTrackingActive()) {
                GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(vertexHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, curModel.getVertices());
                GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(normalHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, curModel.getNormals());
                GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(textureCoordHandle, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, curModel.getTexCoords());

                GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertexHandle);
                GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(normalHandle);
                GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(textureCoordHandle);

                // activate texture 0, bind it, and pass to shader
                GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
                GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextures.get(textureIndex).mTextureID[0]);
                GLES20.glUniform1i(texSampler2DHandle, 0);

                // pass the model view matrix to the shader
                GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mvpMatrixHandle, 1, false, modelViewProjection, 0);

                // finally draw the teapot
                GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, curModel.getNumObjectIndex(), GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, curModel.getIndices());

                // disable the enabled arrays
                GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(vertexHandle);
                GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(normalHandle);
                GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(textureCoordHandle);
            } else {
                GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_CULL_FACE);
                GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(vertexHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, mBuildingsModel.getVertices());
                GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(textureCoordHandle, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, mBuildingsModel.getTexCoords());

                GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertexHandle);
                GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(textureCoordHandle);

                GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
                GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextures.get(3).mTextureID[0]);
                GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mvpMatrixHandle, 1, false, modelViewProjection, 0);
                GLES20.glUniform1i(texSampler2DHandle, 0);
                GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, mBuildingsModel.getNumObjectVertex());

                SampleUtils.checkGLError("Renderer DrawBuildings");
            }

            SampleUtils.checkGLError("Render Frame");

        }

        GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        mRenderer.end();
    }

    private void printUserData(Trackable trackable)
    {
        String userData = (String) trackable.getUserData();
        Log.d(LOGTAG, "UserData:Retreived User Data \"" + userData + "\"");
    }


    public void setTextures(Vector<Texture> textures)
    {
        mTextures = textures;

    }

    private int getTargetIndex(String name){

        for(int i = 0 ; i < modelNames.size() ; i++){
            if(modelNames.get(i).equals(name)){
                return i;
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question? What did you try? There are quite a few examples on the web for rotate on touch for OpenGL, so what is the exact problem?

Comment: I know but I couldn't migrate them with Vuforia @yakobom

Comment: The problem is - we still do not know your problem. People here will not write code for you - but they will gladly help you out with problems. You are not asking any question or presenting any specific difficulty with which we can assist. You couldn't migrate it why? If you want help, show the problematic code and give details.

Comment: Because I don't know how to use native library, :(